# Add hyperlink to prenote for in-text citations

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, natbib

I want to be able to add a clickable link to prenote/postnotes that sends me to the same place as the actual in text citation. I'm using biblatex with natbib.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, natbib=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

I'm trying to hyperlink the prenote of the following cite~\cite[Table 20]{einstein}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible to add 'Table 20' to the same link as the cite link (make 'Table 20' green with the same cite link as '1')? Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps, but from you description is no even clear which bib system you are using -- you used both biblatex and natbib as tag. So add a small but complete example. Also you should say what should happen, if you have two citations keys in the command, e.g. \cite[Table 20]{ash,yyy}

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I've added a small example but I'm not sure what you mean by the two citation keys? As I understood the prenote should only be relevant to one specific citation key.

Comment: but `\cite[Table 20]{einstein,ash}` is allowed input. So what should biblatex do there?

Comment: Oh I see... By testing with ieee style the prenote is only added to the last reference which in your last example is 'ash'. I would want the prenote to also have the same citelink to the reference 'ash' in this case.

Comment: does ieee style sort and compress citations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try sneaking in a `\bibhyperref` into the field formats for `prenote` and `postnote`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{prenote}{\bibhyperref{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\bibhyperref{\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem~\cite[Table~20]{sigfridsson}.

Lorem~\cite[cf.][Table~20]{sigfridsson,worman}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Linked pre- and postnotes]

Conceptually speaking this is a bit tricky, since it is not always clear whether a pre- or postnote belongs to the citation or is there in a meta capacity, this is especially true if there are multiple citation keys in one `\...cite`.