# Biber Biblatex Miktex Texworks

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, miktex, biber, printing

Unable to print the bibliography whatever I do.

1. In Texworks preferences tool configuration, I add Biber
2. I run pdfLaTex - Biber - pdfLaTex individually with TexWorks
3. I update Miktex
   Thanks for help

   ```
   biblio.tex
   \documentclass{report}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}
   \usepackage{comment}
   \usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee
   ]{biblatex}
   \addbibresource{biblio.bib}
   \begin{document}
   \printbibliography
   \end{document}
   ```

My bib file looks like this:

```
@online{knuthwebsite,
author = "Donald Knuth",
title = "Knuth: Computers and
Typesetting",
url = "http://www-csfaculty.
stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
keywords = "latex,knuth"
}

@Book{latexCompanion,
  author       = {Frank Mittelbach, Michael Goossens},
  title        = {The \LaTeX Companion},
  publisher    = {Addison Wesley},
  year         = {2004},
  Annote       = {Ceci est le manuel officiel de \LaTeX. Il contient tout plein de choses, en particulier:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item La structure des fichiers \LaTeX
            \item Instruments de formatage basiques
            \item Tableaux
            \item Formules math\'ematiques
            \item \ldots
        \end{itemize}}
}
```

Comment: your document does not reference anything with `\cite` so will have an empty bibliography.

Comment: As a test, add the command `\nocite{*}` before the bibliography, this will add all citations in the bibliography file. In the final paper, you should omit `\nocite` and rather use `\cite` commands, but for testing the bib entries and your bibstyle `\nocite` helps.

Comment: Double-check that your editor is indeed properly setup for Biber (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). Try running a simple MWE like https://gist.github.com/moewew/cc3f2fb4d986bfc8a2da4efc5b6b1cb7 (without *any* modifications, the used `.bib` file will be present and automatically found on your system) first. Check that you get no errors or warnings in the `.log` and `.blg` files (LaTeX and Biber log). Some common Biber issues are discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864. ...

Comment: ... If you have a multi-user MikTeX installation, make sure to update in Admin and User mode to fully and properly update all packages. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864

Answer (score 1):

I found that only works with `style=ieee` commented.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
natbib=true,
%style=ieee,
]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname48.bib}       
    @online{knuthwebsite,
    author = "Donald Knuth",
    title = "Knuth: Computers and
    Typesetting",
    url = "http://www-csfaculty.
    stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    keywords = "latex,knuth"
    }
    
    @Book{latexCompanion,
    author       = {Frank Mittelbach, Michael Goossens},
    title        = {The \LaTeX Companion},
    publisher    = {Addison Wesley},
    year         = {2004},
    Annote       = {Ceci est le manuel officiel de \LaTeX. Il contient tout plein de choses, en particulier:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item La structure des fichiers \LaTeX
        \item Instruments de formatage basiques
        \item Tableaux
        \item Formules math\'ematiques
        \item \ldots
    \end{itemize}}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname48.bib}

\begin{document}
 See    \cite{latexCompanion}  and \cite{knuthwebsite}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: out]

With `style=ieee` I get

`! Package biblatex-ieee Error: Failed to update citation style.`

`l.62 \docsvlist{cite:comp:inset,cite:dump:inset}`

I could not even run https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573695/161015

Running

This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 20.7)
system commands enabled.
(./q.tex

LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5

L3 programming layer <2020-08-07>

Comment: If you get the error `! Package biblatex-ieee Error: Failed to update citation style.`, then your versions of `biblatex` and `biblatex-ieee` do not match. Update your TeX system thoroughly (on MIkTeX in Admin *and* User mode) to make sure you get matching versions. As always keep in mind that updates may cause conflicts, so it is a good idea to be careful with updates before important deadlines.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the advice. I am not longer a frequent flyer of ieee, so I will wait for an adequate time.